Python can't access Keychain when executed through SSH but it works from a local terminal?
I use Pushbullet CLI to send Pushbullet pushes from the terminal. It works fine when I execute it locally but when I ssh into the machine where it is installed and try to send a push I get a Python traceback:
% pb push test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/keyring/backends/macOS/__init__.py", line 51, in get_password
    return api.find_generic_password(self.keychain, service, username)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/keyring/backends/macOS/api.py", line 144, in find_generic_password
    Error.raise_for_status(status)
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/keyring/backends/macOS/api.py", line 114, in raise_for_status
    raise cls(status, "Unknown Error")
keyring.backends.macOS.api.Error: (-25308, 'Unknown Error')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/bin/pb", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pushbullet_cli/app.py", line 239, in push
    _push(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pushbullet_cli/app.py", line 63, in _push
    pb = _get_pb()
         ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/pushbullet_cli/app.py", line 47, in _get_pb
    password = keyring.get_password("pushbullet", "cli")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/keyring/core.py", line 55, in get_password
    return get_keyring().get_password(service_name, username)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/keyring/backends/chainer.py", line 51, in get_password
    password = keyring.get_password(service, username)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/keyring/backends/macOS/__init__.py", line 57, in get_password
    raise KeyringError("Can't get password from keychain: " "{}".format(e))
keyring.errors.KeyringError: Can't get password from keychain: (-25308, 'Unknown Error')

I guess the problem is that the shell I get when I SSH is different from a local shell, but how do I fix it?

Make sure the key is in the default local keychain (usually named 'login') and that the keychain is unlocked. You can unlock it over SSH by entering the command 'security -i unlock-keychain' to get a password prompt.

@LincD. Unlocking the keychain worked, but what is the difference between a local terminal and an ssh session in this respect? And for how long does the keychain remain unlocked?

I can't cite any documentation offhand, but I think the lock status of the keychain depends on the execution context. As far as I know it should stay unlocked for the duration of the SSH session.

Make sure the key is in the default local keychain (usually named 'login'). Unlock the keychain over SSH by entering the command
security -i unlock-keychain
to get a password prompt.
